# How can I run postgres under root user?

Tags: postgresql

official advice to run postgresql unser a separate user account, with no root privilege.
but, there is a embedded system only with root user. How can I run postgresql in root?

Comment: Run the service under postgres user, later add a database user called "root" and use "psql -U root"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, unless you modify the PostgreSQL source.

Even on an embedded system you should be able to create another user.  Otherwise, don't use PostgreSQL – but running any other database as root is also unnecessarily dangerous.

Comment: yes，I modified postgresql source code, delete all restriction.  This Embedded system has  no commands like addusers etc

Comment: It is not Linux? Nobody says that you need to run a command like `adduser`. Simply modify /etc/passwd`.